# High current regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor, h-bridge, high-current, regulatory

I have a DC motor (I=10A,V=12V.) I want to drive this motor with an H-bridge and want to have speed control with votage (2-12V.)

I think I need a regulator with high current. How can I make a high current regulator?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @winny I just find a picture lm317t with some TIP36 above it, some people to believe that it can provide variable voltage and current of 10 amps, but I didn't try It

Comment: Use PWM on the h-bridge, it's much simpler.